# How to give an abbreviation to a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a namespace hierarchy and want to give an abbreviations for some long namespace names. For example, I have

```
Math::Geometry::OneDimension::
```

and I want to use `Ge` for `Geometry` and `D1` for `OneDimension` thus the following works

```
Math::Ge::OneDimension::
Math::Geoemtry::D1::
Math::Ge::D1::
```

Is it possible to use namespace alias to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access it like that, you'll need to declare namespace aliases inside their enclosing namespaces:

```
namespace Math {
   namespace Ge = Geometry;
   namespace Geometry {
       namespace D1 = OneDimension;
   }
}
```

You can, of course, declare the aliases in other scopes, and access them simply as `Ge` and `D1` in that scope.

Answer (score 8):

You can use namespace aliases:

```
namespace D1 = Math::Geometry::OneDimension;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be using XXX = ...?

Comment: @the_drow:  No, `using` simply brings the namespace in to scope.  It doesn't create an alias for the namespace.

Comment: I'm sure I used the using XXX = YYY some time ago.

Comment: @the_drow: That's C++11 syntax for a type alias, but can't be used for a namespace alias.

Comment: I haven't touched C++ for a very very long time.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace Ge = Math::Geonetry::OneDimension;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can do the aliasing inside the namespace, or, you can do this, from the outside of the namespace :

```
namespace Ge = Math::Geometry;
namespace D1 = Ge::OneDimension;

Ge::element_of_geometry;
D1::element_of_one_dimension;
```

I prefer this solution but use it in a scope to avoid name clashing.